# Back button takes you back to authenticated page after logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When user hits back button after logout, they get Document Expired. However, when user click on this message

> Click Try Again to re-request the document from the website,

in browser, they are able to access an authenticated page again.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951784/logout-from-mvc

Answer (score 2):

It is because the page is cached. For all secure requests you will need to manually kill the cache. You can do something like this:

```
public class SecurePageAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetExpires(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-1));
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
    }
}
```

You would then use it in your controllers like so:

```
[SecurePage]
public ActionResult Index() {
    return View();
}
```

You could also annotate your entire controller or register this globally if the majority of your site is secure.

Answer (score 1):

For a GET Request, you'd expect them to still see the authenticated page on "back" but not be able to interact with it (assuming you use POST for actions).

Since you're talking about a POST Request though (as it's giving you the expired message), it's possible that you're missing the `[Authorize]` attribute from your controller/action which will allow any unauthenticated user to access it, have you checked this?

Comment: I am using post. When user is logged out, i see "Document Expired" which is in a way a desired result. When you click on "try again" button in FF, it will resend those values in controller(i could see that in debug mode) hence user authenticates again. Even if the user hits TRY again, it shouldnt route to authenticated page.