# MVC : How to clear session and close the current browser tab on click of logout link?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to clear the session and the close the browser tab on logout link click. Please help me to do this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For closing the browser, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/853738/how-do-you-close-an-asp-net-mvc-page-from-the-controller). For clearing session, refer [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1951784/logout-from-mvc)

Comment: @Stephen Muecke i tried that.. but its not closing

Answer (score 0):

You can send an ajax request to to an action method which clears the session variables and in the call back, you can close the window.

```
<a id=logoutLink">Logout</a>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){

  $("#logoutLink").click(function(e){
   e.preventDefault();
   $.post("@Url.Action("Logout","User")",function(res){
      if(res.status==="done")
      {
         //close the window now.
         window.close();
      }
   });
  });

});
</script>
```

Now in your UserController, Add the Logout action method

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult Logout()
   {
      Session.Abandon();
      return Json(new { status="done"});
   }
}
```

Reference:
[MVC for clossing browser tab when logout](http:////stackoverflow.com/questions/20223705/mvc-how-to-clear-session-and-close-the-current-browser-tab-on-click-of-logout)

Comment: I want to close the browser tab not to redirect

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to achieve two different things, one of which is a server-side concern, the other a client-side concern.

You could try splitting up these concerns, for example:

**A: Using some [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) laced with tab-closing javascript**

1. Post to Logout controller method
2. Redirect to /LogoutSuccess
3. Put some javascript that closes the browser tab on body load, in the LogoutSuccess view.

**B: A more client-side approach**

1. Perform (in your javascript) a http GET to /Logout
2. Upon 200 OK response, execute some javascript that closes the browser tab.

Answer (score 0):

```
Session.Abandon();
or
Session.Clean();
or
Session[".."]=null;
```

close windows you can use js

```
windows.close();
```

in some browser,it will pop a confirm

Answer (score 0):

This code is from [MSDN](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-clear-session-when-660c1e6b). I have added the async : false to the jQuery call as that is the key to ensure that the call flushes the Server Side session and then the window closes.

```js
<script type="text/javascript"> 
      
 $(document).ready(function () { 
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload',recordeCloseTime); 
 }); 
    
 function recordeCloseTime() { 
 
     $.ajax({ 
      type: "POST", 
            async: false,
         url: "ServiceToClearSession.asmx/RecordCloseTime", 
  });      
 } 

</script>
```